# GLIBC_2.15 required by python

Tags: python, debian

```
python manage.py syncdb
python: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by python)
python: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by python)
```

I use Debian 7.0. I try:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6=2.16-0ubuntu5
E: Version '2.16-0ubuntu5' for 'libc6' was not found
ldd --version
ldd (Debian EGLIBC 2.13-38+deb7u1) 2.13
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

How to fix that?

Thanks

UPDATE

```
/lib/i386-linux-gnu$ ls -la
total 6128
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   12288 Apr 18 08:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root    4096 Apr 18 09:11 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  117960 Dec 23 13:13 ld-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      10 Dec 23 13:13 ld-linux.so.2 -> ld-2.13.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    5552 Dec 23 13:13 libBrokenLocale-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      23 Dec 23 13:13 libBrokenLocale.so.1 -> libBrokenLocale-2.13.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   13856 Dec 23 13:13 libSegFault.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      15 Apr 18 08:52 libacl.so.1 -> libacl.so.1.1.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   34436 Jun 13  2012 libacl.so.1.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      15 Apr 18 08:52 libaio.so.1 -> libaio.so.1.0.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    5016 Jun 21  2012 libaio.so.1.0.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    9916 Dec 23 13:13 libanl-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      14 Dec 23 13:13 libanl.so.1 -> libanl-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      16 Apr 18 08:52 libattr.so.1 -> libattr.so.1.1.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   17864 Jun 13  2012 libattr.so.1.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      15 Apr 18 08:52 libbsd.so.0 -> libbsd.so.0.4.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   50956 Jun 27  2012 libbsd.so.0.4.2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 1360008 Dec 23 13:13 libc-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      12 Dec 23 13:13 libc.so.6 -> libc-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      14 Apr 18 08:52 libcap.so.2 -> libcap.so.2.22
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   15668 Aug 11  2012 libcap.so.2.22
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  185928 Dec 23 13:13 libcidn-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      15 Dec 23 13:13 libcidn.so.1 -> libcidn-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      17 Apr 18 08:52 libcom_err.so.2 -> libcom_err.so.2.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   13836 Mar 20  2013 libcom_err.so.2.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   38416 Dec 23 13:13 libcrypt-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      16 Dec 23 13:13 libcrypt.so.1 -> libcrypt-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      18 Apr 18 08:52 libdbus-1.so.3 -> libdbus-1.so.3.7.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  305416 Jun 13  2013 libdbus-1.so.3.7.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    9844 Dec 23 13:13 libdl-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      13 Dec 23 13:13 libdl.so.2 -> libdl-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      17 Apr 18 08:52 libexpat.so.1 -> libexpat.so.1.6.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  161104 Dec  5 06:47 libexpat.so.1.6.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  114788 Jan  6  2013 libgcc_s.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      19 Apr 18 08:52 libgcrypt.so.11 -> libgcrypt.so.11.7.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  541152 Jul 27  2013 libgcrypt.so.11.7.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      21 Apr 18 08:52 libgpg-error.so.0 -> libgpg-error.so.0.8.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   12736 Aug 27  2012 libgpg-error.so.0.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      16 Apr 18 08:52 libjson.so.0 -> libjson.so.0.1.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   34592 Dec 15  2012 libjson.so.0.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      18 Apr 18 08:52 libkeyutils.so.1 -> libkeyutils.so.1.4
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   13660 Jun 29  2012 libkeyutils.so.1.4
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      16 Apr 18 08:52 liblzma.so.5 -> liblzma.so.5.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  153160 Nov 18  2012 liblzma.so.5.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  148992 Dec 23 13:13 libm-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      12 Dec 23 13:13 libm.so.6 -> libm-2.13.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   13960 Dec 23 13:13 libmemusage.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      18 Apr 18 08:52 libncursesw.so.5 -> libncursesw.so.5.9
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  203084 Jun 27  2012 libncursesw.so.5.9
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   79728 Dec 23 13:13 libnsl-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      14 Dec 23 13:13 libnsl.so.1 -> libnsl-2.13.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   26456 Dec 23 13:13 libnss_compat-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      21 Dec 23 13:13 libnss_compat.so.2 -> libnss_compat-2.13.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   22088 Dec 23 13:13 libnss_dns-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      18 Dec 23 13:13 libnss_dns.so.2 -> libnss_dns-2.13.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   42628 Dec 23 13:13 libnss_files-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      20 Dec 23 13:13 libnss_files.so.2 -> libnss_files-2.13.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   18012 Dec 23 13:13 libnss_hesiod-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      21 Dec 23 13:13 libnss_hesiod.so.2 -> libnss_hesiod-2.13.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   38556 Dec 23 13:13 libnss_nis-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      18 Dec 23 13:13 libnss_nis.so.2 -> libnss_nis-2.13.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   46716 Dec 23 13:13 libnss_nisplus-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      22 Dec 23 13:13 libnss_nisplus.so.2 -> libnss_nisplus-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      16 Apr 18 08:52 libpam.so.0 -> libpam.so.0.83.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   54872 May  4  2012 libpam.so.0.83.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      21 Apr 18 08:52 libpam_misc.so.0 -> libpam_misc.so.0.82.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   13712 May  4  2012 libpam_misc.so.0.82.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      17 Apr 18 08:52 libpamc.so.0 -> libpamc.so.0.82.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   13716 May  4  2012 libpamc.so.0.82.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    5656 Dec 23 13:13 libpcprofile.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      18 Apr 18 08:52 libpng12.so.0 -> libpng12.so.0.49.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  165716 Apr  8  2012 libpng12.so.0.49.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      16 Apr 18 08:52 libpopt.so.0 -> libpopt.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   47048 May 30  2012 libpopt.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  116748 Dec 23 13:13 libpthread-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      18 Dec 23 13:13 libpthread.so.0 -> libpthread-2.13.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   71488 Dec 23 13:13 libresolv-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      17 Dec 23 13:13 libresolv.so.2 -> libresolv-2.13.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   30684 Dec 23 13:13 librt-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      13 Dec 23 13:13 librt.so.1 -> librt-2.13.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  124904 Jun 10  2012 libselinux.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      17 Apr 18 08:52 libslang.so.2 -> libslang.so.2.2.4
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1018724 Jun 30  2012 libslang.so.2.2.4
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      17 Apr 18 08:52 libsysfs.so.2 -> libsysfs.so.2.0.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   46648 Oct  7  2012 libsysfs.so.2.0.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   26404 Dec 23 13:13 libthread_db-1.0.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      19 Dec 23 13:13 libthread_db.so.1 -> libthread_db-1.0.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      15 Apr 18 08:52 libtinfo.so.5 -> libtinfo.so.5.9
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  125424 Jun 27  2012 libtinfo.so.5.9
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      19 Apr 18 08:52 libusb-0.1.so.4 -> libusb-0.1.so.4.4.4
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   30116 Oct  2  2012 libusb-0.1.so.4.4.4
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    9800 Dec 23 13:13 libutil-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      15 Dec 23 13:13 libutil.so.1 -> libutil-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      16 Apr 18 08:52 libuuid.so.1 -> libuuid.so.1.3.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   18000 Dec  9  2012 libuuid.so.1.3.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      16 Apr 18 08:52 libwrap.so.0 -> libwrap.so.0.7.6
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   35312 Jul 29  2012 libwrap.so.0.7.6
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  225688 Jun  8  2012 libx86.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      13 Apr 18 08:52 libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.7
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   95896 Jun 22  2012 libz.so.1.2.7
```

And

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ ls -la
total 10140
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   12288 Apr 18 09:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root    4096 Apr 18 09:11 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  136936 Dec 22 18:55 ld-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      10 Dec 22 18:55 ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> ld-2.13.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    6256 Dec 22 18:55 libBrokenLocale-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      23 Dec 22 18:55 libBrokenLocale.so.1 -> libBrokenLocale-2.13.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   18760 Dec 22 18:55 libSegFault.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      15 Apr 18 08:52 libacl.so.1 -> libacl.so.1.1.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   35320 Jun 13  2012 libacl.so.1.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      15 Jun 21  2012 libaio.so.1 -> libaio.so.1.0.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    5464 Jun 21  2012 libaio.so.1.0.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   14920 Dec 22 18:55 libanl-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      14 Dec 22 18:55 libanl.so.1 -> libanl-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      16 Apr 18 08:52 libattr.so.1 -> libattr.so.1.1.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   18672 Jun 13  2012 libattr.so.1.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      17 Apr 18 08:52 libblkid.so.1 -> libblkid.so.1.1.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  159856 Dec 11  2012 libblkid.so.1.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      15 Apr 18 08:52 libbsd.so.0 -> libbsd.so.0.4.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   51952 Jun 27  2012 libbsd.so.0.4.2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      15 Apr 18 08:52 libbz2.so.1 -> libbz2.so.1.0.4
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      15 Apr 18 08:52 libbz2.so.1.0 -> libbz2.so.1.0.4
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   66824 Jul 29  2012 libbz2.so.1.0.4
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 1599504 Dec 22 18:55 libc-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      12 Dec 22 18:55 libc.so.6 -> libc-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      14 Apr 18 08:52 libcap.so.2 -> libcap.so.2.22
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   17112 Aug 11  2012 libcap.so.2.22
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  190840 Dec 22 18:55 libcidn-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      15 Dec 22 18:55 libcidn.so.1 -> libcidn-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      17 Apr 18 08:52 libcom_err.so.2 -> libcom_err.so.2.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   14672 Mar 20  2013 libcom_err.so.2.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   35104 Dec 22 18:55 libcrypt-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      16 Dec 22 18:55 libcrypt.so.1 -> libcrypt-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      18 Apr 18 08:52 libdbus-1.so.3 -> libdbus-1.so.3.7.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  286488 Jun 12  2013 libdbus-1.so.3.7.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   14768 Dec 22 18:55 libdl-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      13 Dec 22 18:55 libdl.so.2 -> libdl-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      13 Apr 18 08:52 libe2p.so.2 -> libe2p.so.2.3
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   32464 Mar 20  2013 libe2p.so.2.3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      17 Apr 18 08:52 libexpat.so.1 -> libexpat.so.1.6.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  169992 Dec  6 16:17 libexpat.so.1.6.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      16 Apr 18 08:52 libext2fs.so.2 -> libext2fs.so.2.4
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  272608 Mar 20  2013 libext2fs.so.2.4
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   89056 Jan  6  2013 libgcc_s.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      19 Apr 18 08:52 libgcrypt.so.11 -> libgcrypt.so.11.7.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  516128 Jul 27  2013 libgcrypt.so.11.7.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      23 Apr 18 08:52 libglib-2.0.so.0 -> libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1012792 Jan  9  2013 libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      21 Apr 18 08:52 libgpg-error.so.0 -> libgpg-error.so.0.8.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   14112 Aug 17  2012 libgpg-error.so.0.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      19 Apr 18 08:52 libgssglue.so.1 -> libgssglue.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   39192 Jun  8  2012 libgssglue.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      17 Apr 18 08:52 libhistory.so.6 -> libhistory.so.6.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   35232 Dec 30  2012 libhistory.so.6.2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      16 Apr 18 08:52 libjson.so.0 -> libjson.so.0.1.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   39744 Dec 14  2012 libjson.so.0.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      18 Apr 18 08:52 libkeyutils.so.1 -> libkeyutils.so.1.4
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   14320 Jun 29  2012 libkeyutils.so.1.4
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      16 Apr 18 08:52 libkmod.so.2 -> libkmod.so.2.1.3
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   88824 Apr  7  2013 libkmod.so.2.1.3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      16 Apr 18 08:52 liblzma.so.5 -> liblzma.so.5.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  141784 Nov 18  2012 liblzma.so.5.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  530736 Dec 22 18:55 libm-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      12 Dec 22 18:55 libm.so.6 -> libm-2.13.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   18912 Dec 22 18:55 libmemusage.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      17 Apr 18 08:52 libmount.so.1 -> libmount.so.1.1.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  163840 Dec 11  2012 libmount.so.1.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      17 Apr 18 08:52 libncurses.so.5 -> libncurses.so.5.9
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  138864 Jun 27  2012 libncurses.so.5.9
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      18 Apr 18 08:52 libncursesw.so.5 -> libncursesw.so.5.9
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  196576 Jun 27  2012 libncursesw.so.5.9
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      18 Apr 18 08:52 libnl-3.so.200 -> libnl-3.so.200.5.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  106128 Jun 30  2012 libnl-3.so.200.5.2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      23 Apr 18 08:52 libnl-genl-3.so.200 -> libnl-genl-3.so.200.5.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   23712 Jun 30  2012 libnl-genl-3.so.200.5.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   89056 Dec 22 18:55 libnsl-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      14 Dec 22 18:55 libnsl.so.1 -> libnsl-2.13.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   31584 Dec 22 18:55 libnss_compat-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      21 Dec 22 18:55 libnss_compat.so.2 -> libnss_compat-2.13.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   22928 Dec 22 18:55 libnss_dns-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      18 Dec 22 18:55 libnss_dns.so.2 -> libnss_dns-2.13.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   47616 Dec 22 18:55 libnss_files-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      20 Dec 22 18:55 libnss_files.so.2 -> libnss_files-2.13.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   18864 Dec 22 18:55 libnss_hesiod-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      21 Dec 22 18:55 libnss_hesiod.so.2 -> libnss_hesiod-2.13.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   43552 Dec 22 18:55 libnss_nis-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      18 Dec 22 18:55 libnss_nis.so.2 -> libnss_nis-2.13.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   51696 Dec 22 18:55 libnss_nisplus-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      22 Dec 22 18:55 libnss_nisplus.so.2 -> libnss_nisplus-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      16 Apr 18 08:52 libpam.so.0 -> libpam.so.0.83.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   55808 Apr 29  2012 libpam.so.0.83.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      21 Apr 18 08:52 libpam_misc.so.0 -> libpam_misc.so.0.82.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   14480 Apr 29  2012 libpam_misc.so.0.82.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      17 Apr 18 08:52 libpamc.so.0 -> libpamc.so.0.82.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   14488 Apr 29  2012 libpamc.so.0.82.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    6424 Dec 22 18:55 libpcprofile.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      17 Apr 18 08:52 libpcre.so.3 -> libpcre.so.3.13.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  248968 May  1  2012 libpcre.so.3.13.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      27 Apr 18 08:52 libply-splash-core.so.2 -> libply-splash-core.so.2.1.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   76672 Jul  8  2012 libply-splash-core.so.2.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      15 Apr 18 08:52 libply.so.2 -> libply.so.2.1.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   97312 Jul  8  2012 libply.so.2.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      18 Apr 18 08:52 libpng12.so.0 -> libpng12.so.0.49.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  158640 Apr  8  2012 libpng12.so.0.49.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      16 Apr 18 08:52 libpopt.so.0 -> libpopt.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   52296 May 30  2012 libpopt.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      18 Apr 18 08:52 libprocps.so.0 -> libprocps.so.0.0.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   72576 Mar 28  2013 libprocps.so.0.0.1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  131107 Dec 22 18:55 libpthread-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      18 Dec 22 18:55 libpthread.so.0 -> libpthread-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      18 Apr 18 08:52 libreadline.so.6 -> libreadline.so.6.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  284088 Dec 30  2012 libreadline.so.6.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   80712 Dec 22 18:55 libresolv-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      17 Dec 22 18:55 libresolv.so.2 -> libresolv-2.13.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   31744 Dec 22 18:55 librt-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      13 Dec 22 18:55 librt.so.1 -> librt-2.13.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  126232 Jun 10  2012 libselinux.so.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  261184 Mar 31  2012 libsepol.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      17 Apr 18 08:52 libslang.so.2 -> libslang.so.2.2.4
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1252128 Jul  1  2012 libslang.so.2.2.4
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      17 Apr 18 08:52 libsysfs.so.2 -> libsysfs.so.2.0.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   47608 Oct  7  2012 libsysfs.so.2.0.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   31472 Dec 22 18:55 libthread_db-1.0.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      19 Dec 22 18:55 libthread_db.so.1 -> libthread_db-1.0.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      15 Apr 18 08:52 libtinfo.so.5 -> libtinfo.so.5.9
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  167952 Jun 27  2012 libtinfo.so.5.9
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      18 Apr 18 08:52 libtirpc.so.1 -> libtirpc.so.1.0.10
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  158280 Jul 10  2011 libtirpc.so.1.0.10
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      17 Apr 18 08:52 libudev.so.0 -> libudev.so.0.13.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   59992 Apr 28  2013 libudev.so.0.13.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      19 Apr 18 08:52 libusb-0.1.so.4 -> libusb-0.1.so.4.4.4
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   30928 Oct  2  2012 libusb-0.1.so.4.4.4
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   10640 Dec 22 18:55 libutil-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      15 Dec 22 18:55 libutil.so.1 -> libutil-2.13.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      16 Apr 18 08:52 libuuid.so.1 -> libuuid.so.1.3.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   18896 Dec 11  2012 libuuid.so.1.3.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      16 Apr 18 08:52 libwrap.so.0 -> libwrap.so.0.7.6
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   40656 Jul 29  2012 libwrap.so.0.7.6
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      13 Apr 18 08:52 libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.7
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   92752 Jun 22  2012 libz.so.1.2.
```

Comment: silly question, but have you tried just `apt-get install libc6`

Comment: ```libc6 is already the newest version```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that lib.so.6 isn't located where Python is looking for it.

Do:

```
locate libc.so.6
```

Then you could try to do a link from the file to the location where Python is looking (`/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` according to your post).

UPDATE:

You need to update your version of glibc. Look at this post which discussed how to it for Debian: [How to upgrade glibc from version 2.13 to 2.15 on Debian?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10863613/3248346)

Comment: ```locate: can not stat () `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db': No such file or directory``` when I try ```locate libc.so.6```

Comment: In output I have: ```/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6```. The file path and location is the same, but I have that error

Comment: what do you get when you run `ls -al` on each of those absolute paths?

Comment: No! I meant do ls -al /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 and similarly for the other absolute path.

Comment: ```lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Dec 23 13:13 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.13.so``` and ```lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Dec 22 18:55 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.13.so```

Comment: OK - so we see the problem. It's point to version 2.13. You need to update the version of glibc.

Comment: and how to do this? :)

Comment: It's not easy plus it is mega risky. I would first backup all the important files etc you have before messy around with such a core library. Have you considered using a different linux distro? Arch Linux (always bleeding edge) or even Ubuntu?

Comment: Debian runs on VPS server, so I havent got choice: Ubuntu, Debian or Centos :)

Comment: hmm...feel sorry for you dude: https://semitwist.com/articles/article/view/debian-s-package-system-is-shit

Comment: I just went to http://packages.qa.debian.org/e/eglibc.html to locate the binary. However, it seems they never built a 2.14 or 2.15! They went from 2.13 straight to 2.18!

Comment: Very cool. I think, they do the same with python :) So, it will work?

Comment: You can try, but like I said backup your stuff in case you wreck your system.

Comment: I have backup. What I need to do?

Comment: if this fails, you could download the 2.15 version from here: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/. Configure, build and install it yourself. Then go and pray your system will work.

Comment: follow these instructions: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Configuring-and-compiling