# Dart on CentOS 6.5

Tags: dart, centos6.5

I'm trying to get dart up and running on a CentOS 6.5 machine.
The furthest I got so far was getting Dart Editor 64 bit up and running.
When clicking run in Dartium, I get the following error: "Could not start pub serve or connect to pub"

When running Dart from command line, I can see the following error in the command line:

> !ENTRY com.google.dart.tools.core 4 0 2014-12-12 12:22:51.067 !MESSAGE
>   Pub list failed, /home/grim/Apps/dart/dart-sdk/bin/dart:
>   /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by
>   /home/grim/Apps/dart/dart-sdk/bin/dart)
>   /home/grim/Apps/dart/dart-sdk/bin/dart: /lib64/libc.so.6: version`
>   GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by
>   /home/grim/Apps/dart/dart-sdk/bin/dart)

Doing a `ldd -v /bin/sh` I can see that I'm running version 2.3 which is newer than 2.14:

```
libtinfo.so.5 => /lib64/libtinfo.so.5 (0x0000003d3c600000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f2943db3000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2943a1f000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f2943802000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003134e00000)

Version information:
/bin/sh:
        libdl.so.2 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libdl.so.2
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib64/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.11) => /lib64/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib64/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libc.so.6
/usr/lib64/libesets_pac.so:
        libdl.so.2 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libdl.so.2
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libpthread.so.0
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.2) => /lib64/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.3) => /lib64/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libc.so.6
/lib64/libtinfo.so.5:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib64/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib64/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libc.so.6
/lib64/libdl.so.2:
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libc.so.6
/lib64/libc.so.6:
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/lib64/libpthread.so.0:
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.2) => /lib64/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Do I need to downgrade GLIBC (I'm guessing not recommended?) or would a simlink to the newer version be sufficient to fix it?

Update:
Looking at the simlink, I can see I'm actually on 2.12:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Dec  9 11:03 /lib64/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.12.so
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open issue for this (not CentOS specific) https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=11880
The discussion contains some workarounds.

https://github.com/sestegra/patch-dartsdk-linux contains a patch for the source.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/161284 provides some generic background info.
See also
- [How to upgrade glibc from version 2.13 to 2.15 on Debian?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863613) (the workaround I used on Debian)
- http://japhr.blogspot.co.at/2014/09/dart-content-shell-on-debian.html

Comment: I can't really upgrade Glibc on this box due to reasons and that patch doesn't fix it either. Dart editor is running fine after adding some special flags in the DartEditor.ini. Dartium Browser and Dart2js are both failing on the same Glibc errors. so for now I'm going to assume I can't run it on CentOS 6.5 and will continue using it on my Mac rather and copy the compiled JS files over to the CentOS box until I can get rid of some legacy stuff which would allow me to upgrade that CentOS box.

Comment: It can't hurt to add a ping to the issue. They might hope that the issue vanishes over time but it's quite old and still an issue.