# How to get Native Client sdk which compiled by glibc 2.13?

Tags: debian, glibc, google-nativeclient

I am trying to develop PNaCl program on debian7.8. The version of glibc in debian is 2.13 but PNaCl toolchain need glibc 2.15.

For example, when I try to build the program

```
/nacl_sdk/pepper_35/toolchain/linux_pnacl/bin/pnacl-clang++ -o hello_tutorial.bc hello_tutorial.cc -O2 -I/nacl_sdk/pepper_35/include -L/nacl_sdk/pepper_35/lib/pnacl/Release -lppapi_cpp -lppapi
```

and the error message is shown

```
/nacl_sdk/pepper_35/toolchain/linux_pnacl/host_x86_32/bin/clang: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /nacl_sdk/pepper_35/toolchain/linux_pnacl/host_x86_32/bin/../lib/libLLVM-3.4svn.so)
```

My question is, how to download Native client sdk which compiled by glibc 2.13?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome is [built with a Debian sysroot](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/topic/chromium-dev/K6p4b_TiU8U/discussion), but a lot of the tooling (PNaCl included) is built on OSes that have more a recent libc. I'll talk to the team to see if we can also use the sysroot to build the tooling, but in the meantime it's possible to [update your libc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863613/how-to-upgrade-glibc-from-version-2-13-to-2-15-on-debian).

Comment: Thanks @JF Bastien. I have tried your solution but failed. I think that I would like to do another work and wait for the patch.